# Reading current Qt Creator theme from a plugin

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtplugin

There is a plugin for Qt Creator whose UI is just an ActiveX.

The problem is if a user changes the Qt Creator theme, the ActiveX doesn't reflect it.

That is why I need to pass information about colors to the ActiveX, but for that, the plugin has to read theme colors information. Also, the plugin needs to be notified when a current theme has just changed.

I am absolutely a newbie in Qt. Suddenly, I have not found an API to read theme colors.

Is there a way to get current theme colors from a Qt Creator plugin, and how to catch when the theme just changed?

Comment: I'm not sure if Qt creator's theme colors are set using the application palette system, but have a try getting `QApplication::instance()->palette()` and list the colors there and see if they make some sense. Otherwise, you may wish to look into the `QStyle` mechanism perhaps, and see if `Qt Creator` uses its own style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `src/libs/utils/theme/theme.h` which contains the `Utils::Theme` class and function `Utils::Theme *Utils::creatorTheme()`.

Let the plugin depend on the Utils library (with qmake add `QTC_LIB_DEPENDS += utils`, with CMake add `Utils` to `DEPENDS`) and include with `#include <utils/theme/theme.h>` in the source where you want to access the theme.

Get the theme with `Utils::creatorTheme()`. Note that this is set up in Core plugin's `initialize` method, so it is not available in your Plugin's constructor, but only in `initialize` and later (see [Plugin Life Cycle](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-extending-master/plugin-lifecycle.html)).

You can then query the `Theme` for the `Theme::palette()` and the various other task-specific colors.

The theme can not change during runtime, so you are safe with just querying this during startup (or at a later time where you need to set your things up.